# Creating a Custom Styled Prop Using Styled-System

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component

`Styled-System` has a number of props relating to `css grid`: https://styled-system.com/api/#grid-layout

I would like to add, though, a prop called `gridWrap`.  My vision is to take the following CSS code and enable someone to modify the `auto-fit` value vis-a-vis the `gridWrap` prop.  First, here is the base code:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr))
```

My vision is that the prop `gridWrap` would change the `300px` value to whatever is entered.  For example:

```
<MyComponent gridWrap={150} />
```

That would automatically inject the following css code into that component:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr))
```

Now, I know that it is possible to create custom props using `Styled-System`:  https://styled-system.com/custom-props/

But I am having a hard time figuring out from the docs how I am supposed to create the custom `gridWrap` prop that I described above.

Could anyone give me some pointers or show me how it could be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I've gotten it to work:

```js
import { system } from "styled-system";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const MyGrid = styled(Box)`
  display: grid;
  ${system({
    gridWrap: {
      property: "grid-template-columns",
      transform: value => `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(${value}, auto))`
    }
  })}
`;

export { MyGrid };
```

After which I can render my component using `<MyGrid gridWrap="300px">`.